# object dependency on to concrete classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory-pattern, abstract-factory

I'm trying to understand the abstract factory pattern while it's really hard. I've seen the following example, from Head First Design Patterns book, trying to describe dependencies and why being dependent is not good. However, I don't understand the following saying over that code example.

> Because any change to the concrete implementations of pizzas affects
> the `DependentPizzaStore`, we say that the `DependentPizzaStore` “depends on” the pizza
> implementations.

I don't really understand how it affects that class which just initiates by `new`s and uses `bake`, `cut` etc. methods. `DependentPizzaStore` doesn't know anything about the concrete implementations.

```
public class DependentPizzaStore {
  public Pizza createPizza(String style, String type) {
    Pizza pizza = null;
    if (style.equals("NY")) {
      if (type.equals("cheese")) {
        pizza = new NYStyleCheesePizza();
      } else if (type.equals("veggie")) {
        pizza = new NYStyleVeggiePizza();
      } else if (type.equals("clam")) {
        pizza = new NYStyleClamPizza();
      } else if (type.equals("pepperoni")) {
        pizza = new NYStylePepperoniPizza();
      }
    } else if (style.equals("Chicago")) {
      if (type.equals("cheese")) {
        pizza = new ChicagoStyleCheesePizza();
      } else if (type.equals("veggie")) {
        pizza = new ChicagoStyleVeggiePizza();
      } else if (type.equals("clam")) {
        pizza = new ChicagoStyleClamPizza();
      } else if (type.equals("pepperoni")) {
        pizza = new ChicagoStylePepperoniPizza();
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error: invalid type of pizza");
      return null;
    }
    pizza.prepare();
    pizza.bake();
    pizza.cut();
    pizza.box();
    return pizza;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DependentPizzaStore` would need to explicitly know about all the implementations in order to be able to initialize them. Therefore `DependentPizzaStore` is dependent and tight coupled to those implementations. If any of those implementations' constructors were to change then you would need to also change the `DependentPizzaStore`

The Abstract Factory will allow you to provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.

Because your example also has different styles of pizza

```
public interface PizzaFactory {
    string getStyle();
    Pizza createPizza(String type);
}
```

then there is a need for different factories for the differing styles.

```
public class NYStylePizzaFactory implements PizzaFactory {
    
    public string getStyle() { return "NY"; }
    
    public Pizza createPizza(String type) {
        Pizza pizza = null;
        if (type.equals("cheese")) {
            pizza = new NYStyleCheesePizza();
        } else if (type.equals("veggie")) {
            pizza = new NYStyleVeggiePizza();
        } else if (type.equals("clam")) {
            pizza = new NYStyleClamPizza();
        } else if (type.equals("pepperoni")) {
            pizza = new NYStylePepperoniPizza();
        }
        
        if(pizza == null){
            //...throw?
        }
        
        return pizza;
    }
}

public class ChicagoStylePizzaFactory implements PizzaFactory {
    
    public string getStyle() { return "Chicago"; }
    
    public Pizza createPizza(String type) {
        if (type.equals("cheese")) {
            pizza = new ChicagoStyleCheesePizza();
        } else if (type.equals("veggie")) {
            pizza = new ChicagoStyleVeggiePizza();
        } else if (type.equals("clam")) {
            pizza = new ChicagoStyleClamPizza();
        } else if (type.equals("pepperoni")) {
            pizza = new ChicagoStylePepperoniPizza();
        }
        
        if(pizza == null){
            //...throw?
        }
        
        return pizza;
    }
}
```

The `DependentPizzaStore` can now delegate the task of creating the pizza to the factories without having to know anything about implementation details.

```
public class DependentPizzaStore {
    List<PizzaFactory> factories;
    
    public DependentPizzaStore(List<PizzaFactory> factories) {
        this.factories = factories;
    }

    public Pizza createPizza(String style, String type) {
        Pizza pizza = null;
        for (PizzaFactory factory : factories) {
            if (factory.getStyle().equals(style)) {
                pizza = factory.createPizza(type);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pizza == null){
          System.out.println("Error: invalid type of pizza");
          return null;
        }
        pizza.prepare();
        pizza.bake();
        pizza.cut();
        pizza.box();
        return pizza;
    }
}
```

Any additional styles wont affect or cause change to the store. Any changes to how the factory creates pizza also wont affect or cause change to the store.

The store thus depends on abstractions and not on concretions.

Comment: can we say that signature of a constructor is an implementation detail? Since at  your first sentence you say DependentPizzaStore would need to explicitly know about all the implementations .

Comment: @snr Yes knowing the constructor signature is an implementation detail